# How to use Haxe language for html5 as a target

Tags: haxe

I want to develop a multi-platform  game using Haxe but I am not sure where to start. I am  targeting for HTML5 and I want Java-like coding structure classes methods and all.

Comment: nope i am a cocs2dx ,j2me blackberry game developer , but i am willing to start this haxe tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which platforms do you want to use? You said you want to target HTML5, so you mean every platform with a browser? Or also apps?

I personally am a great fan of Flambe, a framework build on top of Haxe. This outputs superfast HTML5 (using both 2D canvas and WebGL if available), Flash (uses Stage3D) which I use as fallback on older browsers but Flash is also used to compile to iOS & Android apps using Adobe AIR. This is all integrated in the framework.
*More info:* http://getflambe.com/
*Quick start guide:* https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki < I hope this will answer your question ("where to start")

You can also use OpenFL http://www.openfl.org/ with Haxe Flixel http://haxeflixel.com/ to build crossplatform games.

Of course as in any other language, read the manual to learn about the Haxe language, this one is getting better and I think will help you too.
http://haxe.org/documentation/introduction/

Comment: every plateform with browser and in mobiles as an app. if you have any suggestion please go ahead !!! Thanks for reply !!!.

Comment: Flambe and OpenFL are both compatible with everything you mentioned. However, Flambe only creates mobile apps through [AIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime).